# Which axiom makes a vector space flat?

Tags: vector-spaces, curvature

First of all, I'm not sure if this question even makes sense, i.e. is there a notion of curvature on a vector space structure. However, when dealing with vector spaces (here I am mostly thinking of tangent spaces on a manifold), we treat (and draw) them as flat. On the other hand, I don't see the flatness assumption (nor any kind of parallelism) in the [vector space axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition).

So, my question is, are and what makes vector spaces flat? What is the difference between the arrows in flat space and e.g. directed arcs of great circles on a 2-sphere? Don't they both satisfy the same axioms?

Comment: "Flat" seems like a topological-geometric assumption. Vector spaces are not necessarily topological-geometrical objects, so they don't need to have a notion of "flatness" or "shape" to them. So the axioms don't have to satisfy that.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's not about curvature, there is something more fundamental that distinguishes $\mathbb{R}^n$ from any other manifold. For any $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$ there is a *canonical* isomorphism $T_p\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$. Any tangent vector $v\in T_p\mathbb{R}^n$ is represented by some path $\alpha$ with $\alpha(0)=p$. The isomorphism is given by $v\mapsto\dot{\alpha}(0)\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

This isomorphism yields a canonical isomorphism between the tangent spaces at two distinct points, and this is something that does not exist on any other manifold.

The concept of *parallel transport* is thus very simple on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Actually, a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be constant, where the definition of constant is very clear.

Intuitively speaking, curvature of a Riemannian manifold $M$ measures how much two vector fields don't commute. But in Euclidean space, having noticed that any tangent vector can be extended canonically to a constant vector field, the fact that every two tangent vectors commute is just the theorem of changing the order of differentiation:

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}.$$

Since every two tangent vectors (or vector fields) commute, the curvature is $0$.

Comment: Would you say that directed lines in $R^2$ and directed arcs in $S^2$ are just two models which satisfy axioms of vector space but the lines have an additional structure, the canonical isomorphism?

Comment: I don't understand the question. How can arcs in $S^2$ satisfy the axioms of vector spaces?

Comment: You can add them and multiply by a scalar and still get a directed arc. Shouldn't it be the same for every geodesic?

Comment: @LittleBrownOne If you're talking about the tangent space at some point, sure. If you're talking about actual geodesics, I challenge you, for $n \geq 2$, to try and rigorously make sense of addition. (Hint: the definition doesn't commute). It's actually rather subtle to specify what it means to take a pair of arcs $c_1,c_2$ both starting at one point and then to move $c_2$ to the start of $c_1$.

The notion you'll end up needing is "parallel transport" but curvature actually measures the failure of parallel transport to commute.

Comment: This is still implicitly using the smooth structure. $\mathbb{R}^4$ has a continuum of homeomorphic, non-diffeomorphic smooth structures. I don't think things work as simply on all exotic structures. I could be mistaken, but I'm doubtful.

Comment: @JHance OK, I see your point. So, it is the commutativity of vector addition which makes the vector space flat?

Comment: What do you mean by "flat", anyway? I think this point needs clarification. Euclidean spaces are the simplest manifolds there are, and curvature is some way to check how much a given manifold is similar to a Euclidean space. So from the first place curvature was invented in such a way that Euclidean spaces would turn out to be flat. Maybe you need to ask what the meaning of "flat" is.